# Angular - How to grab query params from redirect url

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, oauth, amazon-cognito, angular-router

I have an Angular application and I'm trying to implement the OAuth flow using AWS Cognito.

After using the Cognito UI to log the user in I get redirected to my Angular application and the redirect URL contains a token I need to grab. The redirect URL looks like this: http://localhost/redirect?code=123.

However this redirect url does not get picked up by the Angular Router as expected. From the moment query parameters are added the route below doesn't work.

```js
 {
    path:'redirect', // does not work!
    pathMatch: 'prefix',
    component: RedirectComponent
  }
```

I have tried using URL matching and redirecting to a different component but still no luck.

It seems very strange to me that Angular doesn't have a way to hold to query parameters when redirected from a third-party URL so I assume I must be doing something wrong.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

---

EDIT:

After some testing, I think Angular is doing something weird under the hood.

Apparently, there's nothing wrong with my route definition. It's the "code" query parameter Angular doesn't like (I know it sounds insane!)

For example:

http://localhost:4200/redirect?token=123456789 - Works!

http://localhost:4200/redirect?cod=123456789 - Works!

http://localhost:4200/redirect?codee=123456789 - Works!

http://localhost:4200/redirect?code=123456789 - Blows up! Not picked up by route handler

[image: Angular failing to redirect with "code" query param]

The "code" query parameter is not controlled by me (comes from AWS) and I can't change it. Any ideas?

Thanks!

EDIT 2:

Fixed! See below

Comment: what is pathMatch: 'prefix' doing? does removing it help?

Comment: Did you try to do something like: this.router.events.subscribe((event: Event) => console.log(event)); ? Maybe you're not picking it at the event.

Comment: Do you have any other routes interfering with this? Maybe you need to change the order of your routes?

Comment: @danday74 thanks for your comment :). The "prefix" is path match means "match this route if 'redirect' is part of the URL. I have removed and it didn't make any difference. Check my latest edit, I think I have made some progress (even though I have no idea how to fix it!)

Comment: @millenion I have tried that but I don't see anything obvious there. The redirect url gets picked up by my "catch all" route and kicks me back to the landing page. Check my last edit, I think I made some progress though

Answer (score 1):

You can get query parameters by using ActivatedRoute.

You will create a path in  **app-routing.module.ts**

```
      { path: 'user/profile/:user_id', component: UserprofileComponent},
```

And then get the user_id in  **Userprofile.component.ts**

```
constructor(private _Activatedroute: ActivatedRoute) {
    let user_id = this._Activatedroute.snapshot.params['user_id'];
  }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back to me! I think this is a different issue. The solution you proposed works for URL segments but what I'm having issues with are query parameters (stuff like http://localhost:4200/redirect?code=12345678 and not http://localhost:4200/redirect/user/something)

Comment: Then you can use queryParams instead of a snapshot.

Comment: Please see this link https://www.angularjswiki.com/angular/get-query-parameters-in-angular/

Comment: Correct, that now works! I had to remove one of the AWS specific packages I had installed, somehow it was causing angular router to behave in a weird way. Your answer helped me find the issue so thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally got it.

I had installed the `aws-amplify` package and this was causing the behavior depicted in the GIF above.

As soon as I removed the package I was able to redirect to `localhost/redirect?code=123` as expected.